# Entity Framework - Explicitly mapped ID columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Consider the relationship between the following entities:

```
class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}

class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }
}
```

*Okay, nobody in their right minds would have a one-to-one relationship in this context; that's not the issue at play here...*

You'll notice that for each navigation property (`Author` and `Post`) there are explicit Id columns defined (`AuthorId` and `PostId`) respectively.

Personally I don't like this approach (though I can see some potential benefit). I'd prefer EF to manage the Id columns internally for me, and just let me expose a relationship between `Post` and `Author`.

What I want to know is, is there any official recommendation for or against explicit Id columns?

**NOTE:** I do know of one place where explicit Id mapping is valuable, and that is when you're implementing a many-to-many join table. You can use the Ids to create a unique constraint which prevents record duplication for the same many-to-many relationship.

Comment: i dont find this feature in EF, you must need to add related columns in poco, I also will be curious if ther is any feature such like

Comment: @programtreasures You don't find _what_ feature in EF?

Comment: Not sure I get what you're doing.  You have `PostID` in the `Author` table, but no matching column in the `Post` table.  How is that supposed to work?

Comment: @DonBoitnott good spot, updated!

Comment: Ok, with the correction, now I would say that what you have is precisely how I set my tables up.  I like it because it allows me to decide when I want the navigation properties populated, or to just rely upon the ID.

Comment: Which EF version are you in?

Comment: @GertArnold EF 6+ and/or EF Core 1/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to know is, is there any official recommendation for or against explicit Id columns?

Yes:

> It is recommended to include properties in the model that map to
>   foreign keys in the database. With foreign key properties included,
>   you can create or change a relationship by modifying the foreign key
>   value on a dependent object. This kind of association is called a
>   foreign key association. Using foreign keys is even more essential
>   when working with N-Tier applications.

[Entity Framework Relationships and Navigation Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: Would you consider it good practice to go one step further than this, making the FK column ID property `private` so EF can still map to it, and exposing allowed functionality via methods on the entity; i.e. `void DeletePost() { PostId = 0; }`?

Comment: EF 6 needs the Foreign Key Properties to be public.  EF Core introduces Shadow Properties, which allow you to have the Foreign Key values available to the change tracker without declaring them on the Entity. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties

Answer (score 0):

This is not an "official recommendation". But here is how I see it.

You want the navigational properties to be virtual for lazy loading, and you will need the two Id columns for the mapping into the database.

But your code never uses those foreign keys. Here is an example that links a Post with an Author.

```
var p = new Post {Title="Foo"};
p.Author = _db.Authors.First(a => a.Id == 5);
_db.Posts.Add(p);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

You also need to map those fields up into your domain layer to keep track of relations.

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the issue of explicit Id columns. The code example would still work without them, where EF would essentially create this mapping internally. Also, lazy loading is irrelevant in this context.